# How do I extract a certain word from user input (when the word isn't guaranteed to show?)

Tags: python

I'm attempting to run a program that asks for a user's input, scans the input, and if the word 'bob' appears, increase the counter by 1. At the end of the program, the number of times the word 'bob' appears will be displayed.

The code I have written down so far is as follows:

```
count = 0

s = input("Enter a word: ")
for i in s:
if i == 'bob':
    count+=1
print("Number of times bob occurs is: ", count)
```

I understand that for multiple characters this code works, but for an entire word the code doesn't work. I know I have to slice the word from the user input, but how can I do this when the user input can literally be *anything?* I've watched some videos about the practicality of slicing, but I can't seem to figure this out. How can I slice a word that has not only the chance of not appearing, but can appear *anywhere* within a user input?

Comment: `count = s.count('bob')`. See [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

Comment: Your code will not work for any input. What you're calling `i` is a single-character string. One character can never equal three characters. If you're just interested in counting the number of occurrences of the substring `"bob"`, then you can simply do `print(input("Enter a string: ").count("bob"))`

Comment: @PaulM. Ah, I understand! I understood that using "i" wasn't working to call multiple characters, but for singular characters. I was just stuck. I was using the Boolean value "or" to connect multiple characters together. Thank you for the information.